# Why is $Y=\beta_0 x^{\beta_1} e$ a linear model?

Tags: statistics, logarithms, transformation, regression

Why is $Y=\beta_0 x^{\beta_1} e$ a linear model? When we apply the transform, it becomes $lnY = ln\beta_0+\beta_1 lnx +lne$, and why is it still linear when the $\beta_0$ part is under ln?

Comment: Your first model is not linear, as $\beta_1$ appears as an exponent. However, the second model is linear through the transformation. Notice we can replace the $\ln(\beta_0)$ with $\alpha$ and we still have coefficients coming into the model linearly.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/488677/119261